# How to use animate in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, animation, delphi-7

How do I use the animate box that you find in win32 tab in Delphi 7. I have searched the internet but all I found was how to animate your form. The help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `TAnimate`, you load an AVI file into it, and set the `Active` property to `True`. Or you can use build it animations like "copy", "find", etc.

Comment: I tried loading a .avi video but gave me a error cannot open avi and the same thing happens if I try set the action property to true.

Comment: @Craig - You cannot use *any* avi, only uncompressed or RLE8 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Sertac can you tell me where I can find the right avi file. A link will be great.

Comment: I found a video converter and converted the video and it worked thanks.